# How do I 'reset' a method on call?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, slideshow

Good day all,

I am currently stuck with an issue here on javascript.

I have an automated slideshow loop based on this http://jsfiddle.net/pdb4kb1a/2.

Now I also have arrows added to the images so a user should be able to go back and forth himself as well. 
The problem here is, when I call on the onClick() it goes on re-calling the slideShow(n) method without 'interrupting' nor 'resetting' the other. 
So what I end up with is a recall on a loop while the other is still running, which creates a very fast and disorientated loop after clicking the arrow buttons.

How do I reset my slideShow() loop on call?

```
var imgArray = ['img/sleutels.jpg', 'img/naamborden.jpg', 'img/leer.jpg'];
var photoIndex = 2;                                                             
var photoId = document.getElementById('photoSlide');



function setIndex(n) {                          
    slideShow((photoIndex + n));                            
}


function slideShow(n) {
    photoId.className += "fadeOut";                                             
    setTimeout(appear, 500);                                                    
    photoIndex++;
    if (photoIndex == imgArray.length) {                                        
        photoIndex = 0; 
    }
    console.log(photoIndex);
   setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);                                                 
}


function appear() { 
    photoId.src = imgArray[photoIndex];     
    photoId.className = "";                     
}


slideShow();
```

Kind regards

Comment: Can you create a demo in jsfiddle where we can see the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `setIndex(2)`

Comment: @Rajesh. that's the fiddle link of OP's reference. but not his working problem. right?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle is what my code is based on, I found it fair to have these credits to that certain OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better structure I would nest the timeouts, then store the id of the timeout and clear it:

```
var appearId, showId;

function setIndex(n) {
    slideShow((photoIndex + n));
}

function slideShow(n) {
    photoId.className += "fadeOut";
    photoIndex++;

    if (photoIndex == imgArray.length) {
        photoIndex = 0;
    }
    console.log(photoIndex);

    if (appearId) { clearTimeout(appearId) }
    appearId = setTimeout(appear, 500);
}

function appear() {
    photoId.src = imgArray[photoIndex];
    photoId.className = "";

    if (showId) { clearTimeout(showId) }
    showId = setTimeout(slideShow, 4500);
}

slideShow();
```

Comment: This immediatly worked for me, it just bugs me that even after spending hours on it I still demanded help... Nevertheless I am thankful !

Comment: Nice... I didn't even test it :). Years of programming javascript, I remember being in your shoes. Give it time, it takes many years.

Comment: There is just one thing I do not fully understand, when you say appearId = setTimeout(appear, 500) this also directly calls on the function? Cause in syntax it looks like only  'filling'  a val instead of actually calling on it.

Comment: It fills the val with a number id, i.e. 100, then sets the timeout to the function. It doesn't actually execute till 500ms later though.

Comment: I understand the interval of 500, but so it DOES call on it while being filled at the same time? I come from a php and java world so this looks weird to me, since there is no direct execution syntax but two melded into eachother? Am I correct on this?

Comment: No it fills it immediately, then calls the function 500ms later.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I meant. But appear(); is a void so it is weird to see a var that is being filled calling on a void function as well. I am sorry if I do not appear very clear in explaining my struggle with this but it is one of the causes I could not figure out a proper timer since I thought filling a var with a call on a void was allowed.

Comment: setTimeout is not a void. setTimeout is returning the number and storing a reference to appear. Since appear does not have () after it, it is not called, only the reference is passed to setTimeout.

Comment: Yes, this I understand.. Sorry, as I said I may not be clear in my issue. I think I will just let it pass since time is running out. Lots of thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to save the slideshow timeout in a variable and reset it in the onclick ? Something like that :

```js
var imgArray = [
    'http://placehold.it/300x200',
    'http://placehold.it/200x100',
    'http://placehold.it/400x300'],
    curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 3000;

var slideTimeout;

document.getElementById('nextButton').addEventListener('click', onNextClick);

function slideShow() {
    document.getElementById('slider').className += "fadeOut";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('slider').src = imgArray[curIndex];
        document.getElementById('slider').className = "";
    },1000);
    nextIndex();
    slideTimeout = setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}
slideShow();

function onNextClick(domEvent){
  if (slideTimeout)
    clearTimeout(slideTimeout);
  
  nextIndex();
  slideShow();
}

function nextIndex(){
  curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
}
```

```css
#nextButton{
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding:4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#slider {
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 1s; 
    display: block;
}

#slider.fadeOut {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<span id="nextButton">NEXT</span>
<img id="slider" src="http://placehold.it/50x200">
```

There's still some code to change because I don't really like the way you handle the index but it works... You just have to enhance this code to handle "previous" image and you'll have what you want ;) Hope it helps

Comment: This came in to mind for a short while, but could not focus anymore working it out. Thanks, I will give it a go!

Comment: Unfortunatly I keep being in the same loop, maybe I have not understood 'Set the new id'  right? Cause here is where I set slideshow_timeout = setTimeout(slideShow, 5000) and call on slideshow.

Comment: I updated my post using your snippet to illustrate what I meant ;) Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the effort :)

Comment: The reason is left possibly less efficient in some ways is because I am a student and want to know exactly what is going on step-by-step before I make my own shortcuts. (I have my own assumption that when I can make the code more efficient on my own I can declare understanding it)

Comment: Once my main problem (proper timer clearing) is solved I will ofc move on with making my code more efficient